Estoy intentando de combinar las filas en una sola columna
Se muestra una imagen de base de datos en formato csv

datos_consumo<-read.csv("Consumo.csv")

da_consumo<-as_tibble(datos_consumo) %>% 
clean_names()

da_consumo1<-da_consumo %>%
select(consumo,consumo_1,consumo_2,consumo_3,consumo_4,consumo_5,consumo_6,consumo_7,consumo_8,consumo_9,consumo_10)

# PARA COMBINAR LAS FILAS DE CONSUMO EN UNA ÚNICA COLUMNA DE CONSUMO
df1<-data.frame(x=da_consumo1$consumo)

df2<-data.frame(x=da_consumo1$consumo_1)

# Se imprimó mal la única columna porque no se podría combinar 
# cada elemento de una segunda y tercera fila en un elemento de una nueva columna. 
consumo<-rbind(df1,df2)

Se necesita que se vea algo así como resultado


Sería buena idea que compartieras una parte del CSV para poderte ayudar de mejor forma, por lo pronto use una parte del como ejemplo:
Numero,Pais,Consumo_1,Emisiones_1,Consumo_2,Emisiones_2,Total_de_emis,Productos_an
1,Argentina,10.51,37.2,38.66,41.53,2140.65,2109.8
2,Australia,24.14,85.44,46.12,45.34,1859.55,1853.46
3,Albania,10.88,38.51,27.68,34.12,1733.73,1689.62
4,Iceland,21.69,76.77,26.87,32.86,1705.55,1679.75
5,New Zealand,22.29,78.9,34.98,37.58,1709.8,1668.67

El código en R quedaría así:
library(tibble)
library(janitor)
library(dplyr)

# Leer archivo CSV y limpiar los nombres de las columnas
data_consumo <- read.csv("data.csv", header = TRUE) %>%
  clean_names()

# Convertir dataframe a tibble
da_cns <- as_tibble(data_consumo)

# Seleccionar las columnas correctas
da_cns <- select(da_cns, consumo_1, consumo_2)

# Combinar las columnas en una única columna
consumo <- bind_rows(
  data.frame(x = da_cns$consumo_1),
  data.frame(x = da_cns$consumo_2)
)

# Imprimir el resultado
print(consumo)

Lo que da como resultado:
       x
1  10.51
2  24.14
3  10.88
4  21.69
5  22.29
6  38.66
7  46.12
8  27.68
9  26.87
10 34.98

En el caso del problema que tienes con el CSV original, de esta forma optimizada debería de funcionar:
library(tibble)
library(janitor)
library(dplyr)

data_consumo <- read.csv("data.csv", header = TRUE) %>%
  clean_names()

da_cns <- as_tibble(data_consumo)

da_cns <- select(da_cns, starts_with("consumo"))

consumo <- bind_rows(lapply(da_cns, function(x) data.frame(x)))

print(consumo)

El paquete dplyr viene con la función starts_width que te permite obtener los campos que empiecen con ciertas letras. Para bind_rows usamos lapply que permite aplicar una función sobre una columna.
Documentación
Select variables that match a pattern — starts_with • tidyselect
lapply function - RDocumentation

Así es no,   necesito que se imprime como 10.51
38.66
55.48
1.56
4.36
11.39
195.08
103.11
8.77
0
0.49
24.14
46.12
33.86
9.87
17.69
8.51
234.49
70.46
11.03
0.19
8.73

Por eso use datos como ejemplo, de donde saco el dataset para poder replicar tu problema y ver si mi solución funciona?

No se logra de editar lo que he publicado para qué lo entiendes mejor, pero intento de explicarte bien.  Lo primero es trasponer cada fila y después combinar todas las filas transpuestas que se convertirán en una sola columna como resultado final.   En mi publicación, vaya a buscar el mismo resultado.  No solo a combinar dos filas (segunda y tercerca fila) transpuestas.  Es necesario combinar todas las filas transpuestas , por lo que solo se quedan en una sola columna.

@DavidMendez me parece que no quedó claro lo que intentaba comunicar. Si quieres que obtenga el mismo resultado, necesito contar con los mismos datos. Por favor, comparte el archivo CSV para que pueda trabajar con esa información. Por esa razón utilicé datos de prueba, no puedes esperar que un ejemplo arroje los mismos resultados si no está usando los mismos datos.

No sé cómo hago para compartir el archivo CSV.  Regálame el correo para que se te enviara el archivo y otra imagen de referencia.

Puedes compartir un enlace de Drive o algún otro proveedor donde tengas el archivo. Esto es un sitio de Q&A y debe ser quien pregunta quien provea lo necesario para replicar el error.
